# Working with Microsecond Time Stamps in PySpark

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe with the following time format `20190111-08:15:45.275753`. I want to convert this to timestamp format keeping the microsecond granularity. However, it appears as though it is difficult to keep the microseconds as all time conversions in pyspark produce seconds?

Do you have a clue on how this can be done? Note that converting it to pandas etc will not work as the dataset is huge so I need an efficient way of doing this. Example of how i am doing this below

```
time_df = spark.createDataFrame([('20150408-01:12:04.275753',)], ['dt'])
res = time_df.withColumn("time",  unix_timestamp(col("dt"), \
format='yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss.000').alias("time"))
res.show(5, False)
```

Comment: is the timestamp like `20190111-08:15.45.275753` or `2019-01-11-08:15.45.275753`?

Answer (score 3):

Normally timestamp granularity is in seconds so I do not think there is a direct method to keep milliseconds granularity.

In pyspark there is the function `unix_timestamp` that :

> `unix_timestamp(timestamp=None, format='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')`
>
> Convert time string with given pattern (`'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'`, by default)
>       to Unix time stamp (**in seconds**), using the default timezone and the default
>       locale, return null if fail.
>
> ```
> if `timestamp` is None, then it returns current timestamp.
>
> >>> spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "America/Los_Angeles")
> >>> time_df = spark.createDataFrame([('2015-04-08',)], ['dt'])
> >>> time_df.select(unix_timestamp('dt', 'yyyy-MM-dd').alias('unix_time')).collect()
> [Row(unix_time=1428476400)]
> >>> spark.conf.unset("spark.sql.session.timeZone")
> ```

A usage example:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
res = df.withColumn(colName,  F.unix_timestamp(F.col(colName), \
    format='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.000').alias(colName) )
```

What you might do is splitting your date string (`str.rsplit('.', 1)`) keeping the milliseconds apart (for example by creating another column) in your dataframe.

**EDIT**

In your example the problem is that the time is of type string. First you need to convert it to a `timestamp` type: this can be done with:

```
res = time_df.withColumn("new_col", to_timestamp("dt", "yyyyMMdd-hh:mm:ss"))
```

Then you can use `unix_timestamp`

```
res2 = res.withColumn("time",  F.unix_timestamp(F.col("parsed"), format='yyyyMMdd-hh:mm:ss.000').alias("time"))
```

Finally to create a columns with milliseconds:

```
res3 = res2.withColumn("ms", F.split(res2['dt'], '[.]').getItem(1))
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me. It gives a null value on the field.

Comment: Did you change the format so that it fits your column?

Comment: Yes im using this - yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss.000 and my time looks like this 20190104-01:12:04.275753

Comment: Can you post the code to create a dataframe with the same schema you are using?

Comment: I've updated the post description to include this detail

Comment: I am a bit confused with this as this doesnt really give me one column of type timestamp with milli / micro second level granularity?

Comment: milliseconds should be `SSSSSS`. I tried `time_df.withColumn("parsed", to_timestamp("dt", format="yyyyMMdd-hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS"))`  but it is not working. You can try yourself. More than that I can't do it.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a work around for this using to_utc_timestamp function in pyspark, however not entirely sure if this is the most efficient though it seems to work fine on about 100 mn rows of data. You can avoid the regex_replace if your timestamp string looked like this - 
1997-02-28 10:30:40.897748

```
 from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace, to_utc_timestamp

 df = spark.createDataFrame([('19970228-10:30:40.897748',)], ['new_t'])
 df = df.withColumn('t', regexp_replace('new_t', '^(.{4})(.{2})(.{2})-', '$1-$2-$3 '))
 df = df.withColumn("time", to_utc_timestamp(df.t, "UTC").alias('t'))
 df.show(5,False)
 print(df.dtypes)
```